# Python subprocess hangs

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm executing the following subprocess...

`p.call(["./hex2raw", "<", "exploit4.txt", "|", "./rtarget"])`

...and it hangs.

But if I execute `kmwe236@kmwe236:~/CS485/prog3/target26$ ./hex2raw < exploit4.txt | ./rtarget` then it executes fine. Is there something wrong with using the input or piping operator?

I also tried `sp.call(["./hex2raw", "<", "exploit4.txt", "|", "./rtarget"], shell=True)`

The entire code looks like this **UPDATED WITH SUGGESTIONS**

```
import subprocess as sp
import pdb

for i in range(4201265,4201323):
    pdb.set_trace()
    d = hex(i)[2:]
    output = " "
    for i in range(len(d),0,-2):
        output = output + d[i-2:i] + " "

    out_buffer = "00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00" + output + "00 00 00 00"

    text_file = open("exploit4.txt", "w")
    text_file.write("%s" % out_buffer)

 #   sp.call(["./hex2raw", "<", "exploit4.txt", "|", "./rtarget"], shell=True)
    with open("exploit4.txt") as inhandle:
        p = sp.Popen("./hex2raw",stdin=inhandle,stdout=sp.PIPE)
        p2 = sp.Popen("./rtarget",stdin=p.stdout,stdout=sp.PIPE)
        [output,error] = p2.communicate()
```

I'm getting an error is

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

After debugging it occurs at the fire subprocess call `p = sp.Popen("./hex2raw",stdin=inhandle,stdout=sp.PIPE)`

Comment: Don't forget to close the file after you write it.

Comment: Also, as a general rule, don't update the code in your question with the best answer, or your question will become meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using redirection and piping, you have to enable `shell=True`

```
sp.call(["./hex2raw", "<", "exploit4.txt", "|", "./rtarget"],shell=True)
```

but it would be much cleaner to use `Popen` on both executables and feeding the contents of `exploit4.txt` as input. Example below, adapted to your case:

```
import subprocess

    with open("exploit4.txt") as inhandle:
        p = subprocess.Popen("./hex2raw",stdin=inhandle,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        p2 = subprocess.Popen("./rtarget",stdin=p.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        [output,error] = p2.communicate()
        print(output)
        # checking return codes is also a good idea
        rc2 = p2.wait()
        rc = p.wait()
```

Explanation:

1. open the input file, get its handle `inhandle`
2. open the first subprocess, redirecting `stdin` with `inhandle`, and `stdout` to an output stream. Get the pipe handle (p)
3. open the second subprocess, redirecting `stdin` with previous process `stdout`, and `stdout` to an output stream
4. let the second process `communicate`. It will "pull" the first one by consuming its output: both processes work in a pipe fashion
5. get return codes and print the result

Note: you get "format error" because one or both executables are actually shell or other non-native executables. In that case, just add the `shell=True` option to the relevant `Popen` calls.

Comment: I tried this, still no luck. What would be the `Popen` syntax?

Comment: I was brewing an example using 2 grep commands, and I have adapted it to your case.

Comment: semantics look great, but something is still wrong -- check the post (updated with new code and error)

Comment: oh, those must be shell scripts. Try adding `shell=True` for the ones executables being shell scripts (if you don't know, try to open them in a text editor), this time it will work better :)

Comment: It works well - thanks.
I would just argue rc2 = p2.wait() and rc = p.wait() are a little confusing (since you do not wait any more, and just get the status code), I think it's a little bad for readability.